# When writing inline assembly language on Mac OS X 10.6 in XCode 4.0.2, what assembler syntax is used?

Tags: xcode, macos, assembly, osx-snow-leopard

I would like to use inline assembly in XCode 4.0.2 in C/C++ code.  Since XCode uses GCC and Clang with LLVM, what assembler syntax do I use when inlining the code ?  Do I use GAS (GNU Assembler), something specific to Clang+LLVM (no idea what this is called) ?  Also, is it possible to support NASM syntax inline in XCode ?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 2):

Clang uses its own assembler, which is highly compatible with GAS (the details are on Clang's [Compatibility](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#inline-asm) page).

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know of any samples showing more than 1 line of inline code for Clang ?